# Using git with sources which are provided as a tarball

Tags: git

The scenario is this:

- Some provider provides source code in tgz format. I have no access to their repositories.
- I opened the sources, and created a local git repository with the sources.
- I do changes to the sources, and commit them to my git.
- Now the provider provides a new version of the source code.
- I want to merge the new code in my git repositories.

Is this possible?

(I cannot ask the provider to provide the source in other means)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Keep the original code in branch A

2) Branch A to B and do your development in branch B

3) When you get the updated tgz, unpack it on branch A,
so branch A only contains original code and their updates.

4) You can now choose if you want to rebase B on A, or if
you want to merge. I prefer rebase

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing, and it works great so far!

Comment: As simple as this :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

1) Download the source - `wget -c <source_url>`

2) Create folder for upstream - `mkdir <project>_upstream`

3) Untar it - `tar --strip 1 -xvzf <tar_file> -C <project>_upstream`

4) `cd` into `<project>_upstream` and initialize the git repo

5)  Go up a level and do a `git clone <project>_upstream <project>`

Repeat steps 1 & 3 followed by a `git pull` whenever you want to update your repo.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not a fan of creating multiple directories for the same project though, even temporarily.

Comment: That's fine. I don't like making direct changes in the repo I'm working on in case I screw up accidentally.